# Converting this ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-5.3, ereg-replace

I need to change the ereg replace to a preg replace on this statement:

```
$return = trim(ereg_replace(' +',' ',preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','',strtolower($input))));
```

However it errors when I make the change.

Any ideas on the fix to make this work?

Comment: The error would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
  $return = trim(preg_replace('/ +/',' ',preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','',strtolower($input))));
```

Comment: Why are you posting the same thing I answered? Even worse your example will mismatch or actually not match the blank space before the + sign.

Comment: sorry my connection is slow, I didn't get the update, c'mon i'm sorry buddy, you didn't need to undervote this..! calm down, and it's not exactly the same, "/ +/" is the right way, also used in the manual to express regular forms http://php.net/manual/it/function.preg-replace.php